# plotting specific columns of a data frame in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, multiple-columns

| ind | set | inst_0 | inst_1 | inst_2 | Inst_3 | inst_4 | inst_5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 20 | 30 | 50 | 55 | 58 | 60 |
| 0 | 2 | 34 | 44 | 46 | 67 | 89 | 70 |
| 0 | 3 | 37 | 89 | 78 | 80 | 90 | 98 |
| 0 | 4 | 23 | 45 | 67 | 89 | 87 | 89 |
| 1 | 1 | 34 | 56 | 65 | 78 | 77 | 89 |
| 1 | 2 | 23 | 32 | 45 | 55 | 66 | 77 |
| 1 | 3 | 35 | 69 | 88 | 99 | 98 | 57 |
| 1 | 4 | 23 | 45 | 56 | 78 | 89 | 99 |
| 2 | 1 | 23 | 34 | 55 | 55 | 77 | 88 |
| 2 | 2 | 12 | 44 | 55 | 67 | 88 | 90 |
| 2 | 3 | 12 | 66 | 77 | 91 | 44 | 99 |
| 2 | 4 | 45 | 55 | 88 | 31 | 56 | 100 |

I have a data frame like this above and I would like to make a plot showing this kind of a trend like in the graph below( this is only made for 4 individual in a same set) for the combinations of for example Ind0-set1, Ind1-set1, Ind2-set2...,Ind0-set2,Ind1-set2 and second question is that how to plot multiple line graph separately for each set in one graph?

[image]

I am not sure to use ggplot2 or it can be done plot function too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to do this using `ggplot2` then the first step would be to reshape your data to long or tidy format using e.g. `tidyr::pivot_longer`:

```r
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

# Reshape to long
dat <- dat %>%
  # Convert all column names to lower case
  rename_with(tolower) %>%
  pivot_longer(-c(ind, set), names_to = "inst", values_to = "value", names_prefix = "inst_")
```

After doing so you could create a plot showing all individuals for all sets by using facetting:

```
ggplot(dat, aes(inst, value, color = factor(ind), group = ind)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_point() +
  facet_wrap(~set)
```

[image]

Or you could filter your data for your desired combinations to create a plot for e.g. just one set like so:

```r
dat_filtered <- dat[dat$set == 1, ]

ggplot(dat_filtered, aes(inst, value, color = factor(ind), group = ind)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_point()
```

[image]

**DATA**

```
dat <- data.frame(
  ind = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L),
  set = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L),
  inst_0 = c(20L, 34L, 37L, 23L, 34L, 23L, 35L, 23L, 23L, 12L, 12L, 45L),
  inst_1 = c(30L, 44L, 89L, 45L, 56L, 32L, 69L, 45L, 34L, 44L, 66L, 55L),
  inst_2 = c(50L, 46L, 78L, 67L, 65L, 45L, 88L, 56L, 55L, 55L, 77L, 88L),
  Inst_3 = c(55L, 67L, 80L, 89L, 78L, 55L, 99L, 78L, 55L, 67L, 91L, 31L),
  inst_4 = c(58L, 89L, 90L, 87L, 77L, 66L, 98L, 89L, 77L, 88L, 44L, 56L),
  inst_5 = c(60L, 70L, 98L, 89L, 89L, 77L, 57L, 99L, 88L, 90L, 99L, 100L)
)
```